# Scale SVG to a fixed height

Tags: html, css, svg

I have many countries flags that are saved as SVG with a fixed height and width, which are different between each flag (some are 1000x700 others are 1500x300, etc.)

Example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000" height="700"></svg>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aypvdj

What I'm trying to do is to scale it to a much smaller size.

I don't understand how to scale with a fixed height (e.g. 80px) and with the width autoscaling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the width, change the height to 80px and add a viewBox e.g.

```
height="80" viewBox="0 0 1000 700"
```